# How can I finish this sentence?

Tags: writing

Help me finish this sentence:

when students have formed a habit of speaking comfortably and confidently, they will benefit when they step out into society and later chapters of their lives.

I feel like I have to add something before *later chapters of their lives.* and change it into *in the later chapters of their lives,* can you guys drop me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wrote as in:

> **Having** formed a habit of speaking comfortably and confidently, **students** will benefit they step out **into the** society and later chapters of their lives.

you use **into the** previously, take a look at this sentence:
the economy is embedded **in a** society and culture.